# Vertex-cut/Edge-cut Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph of order $n\geq4$ and let $k$ be an integer with $2\leq k \leq n-2$.

a. Prove that if $G$ is not $k$-connected , then $G$ contains a vertex-cut $U$ with $|U|=k-1$.

b. Prove that if $G$ is not $k$-edge-connected, then $G$ contains an edge-cut $X$ with $|X|=k-1$.

Comment: What have you done? Can you define the terms that you are using? Do these follow from the definitions?

Comment: Both of these seem to be the definition of [vertex-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) and [edge-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) given in wikipedia.

Comment: a. Since $G$ is not $k$-connected, then there exists a set of $k-1$ vertices whose removal disconnects the graph. Let $U$ be the set containing these $k-1$ vertices, that is $U$ is the minimum vertex-cut of $G$ where $|U|=k-1$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Paul, That seems right to me, and a similar argument would work for part b. Note that $U$ doesn't have to be the **minimum** vertex -cut, but the minimal vertex-cut will of course have at most $k-1$ vertices.